# how can we select certain columns only in the database of a server and make an csv file or excel?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a database with many tables and one particular table has columns:

1. name
2. e-mail
3. no:
4. address
5. start_date(include time also)
6. end_date(include time also)
7. id

I need to select only the name and the e-mail addresses of the persons satisfying the condition that:

1. he appears twice in the list
2. the difference between the time in fields Start_date and end_date must be 10+minutes

Comment: What criteria determines whether he exists twice? Email?

Comment: @SeanW his name or e-mail.....either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the table onto itself like this:

```
SELECT `a`.`name`, `a`.`email`
FROM `table_name` `a`
JOIN `table_name` `b` ON
  (`a`.`name` = `b`.`name` OR `a`.`email` = `b`.`email`)
  AND `a`.`id` != `b`.`id`
  AND `a`.`end_date` < DATE_ADD(`a`.`start_date`, INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)
GROUP BY `a`.`name`
```

[Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4f1d6/5)

While you loop the results you can easily create valid CSV data using [`fputcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php).

Comment: why this line: 


  AND `a`.`id` != `b`.`id`

Comment: what does "" JOIN `table_name` `b` "" mean? like what is use of b?

Comment: @user1424394 You are joining the table onto itself to look for duplicates. So you need to assert that `a.id != b.id` to ensure that the current row does not find a duplicate because it is looking at a copy of itself. The use of the `a` and `b` alias is required, because you are joining the table onto itself so you cannot reference it by the table name, as MySQL will not know which instance of the table you are referring to. People often also use aliases simply to make the query shorter and more readable.

Comment: Dude...... AND `a`.`end_date` < DATE_ADD(`a`.`start_date`, INTERVAL 10 MINUTE).....is that line correct? does it give members with time diff more than10 or less than 10?

Comment: i think it must be > instead of < to get 10+mins

Comment: That says `is end_date less than (start_date + 10 minutes)` which I think is what you want, but you can easily play around with that condition to see that you get what you want.

Comment: ya i get...what you've given is opposite of wht i've asked but i can figure it out. anyways thanks.

Comment: No worries, just switch it to a `>` then. Sorry about that, I misread the question.

Answer (score 1):

In mysql, you need a subquery:

```
select t.*
from t join
     (select name, email, count(*) as cnt
      from t
      where time_to_sec(timediff(start_date, end_date)) > 10*60
      group by name, email
      having count(*) > 1
     ) dups
     on t.name = dups.name and t.email = dups.email
```

Comment: how do i get the csv file from this?

Comment: That depends entirely on the database and the interface you are using for it.  You can run this in a query interface, such as SQL Server Management Studio or TOAD and just export it.  In SQL Server, you can save it to a temporary table and then use bulk export to save it to a file.  Other databases have similar functionality.